# Network list of nodes issue - list changes as soon as I add another node

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, networkx

I've faced a few problems in the process of Binary Graph dev.

So far my problem is an unstable list of nodes. Once I add nodes the output list is totally reordered.

Below is my output.

Has anyone faced such a problem before?

```
g.node.items()
[(8, {'location': 'root'}), (9, {'location': 'right'}), (5, {'location': 'left'}), (15, {'location': 'right'})]
g.add_node(12, location='left')
g.node.items()
[(8, {'location': 'root'}), (9, {'location': 'right'}), (12, {'location': 'left'}), (5, {'location': 'left'}), (15, {'location': 'right'})]
g.add_node(6, location='right')
g.node.items()
[(5, {'location': 'left'}), (6, {'location': 'right'}), (8, {'location': 'root'}), (9, {'location': 'right'}), (12, {'location': 'left'}), (15, {'location': 'right'})]
```

Comment: Judging from the `.items()`, `node` is a `dict` which is unordered.

Comment: +1 to korylprince. But to make sure: what do you get from `type(g.nodes)` or `g.nodes`? What type is `g`?

Comment: type(G.nodes())
<type 'list'>

Comment: Note that `g.node` is **not** the same as `g.nodes()` in networkx.  The former is the internal dictionary, while the latter is the accessor function, which provides a list of the nodes present in the internal dictionary.

Comment: Also, this looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Part of the reason that dictionaries aren't ordered is that usually you don't need them to be. You can look things up, compare two dicts, etc. without worrying about the order. If you need an order, you can impose one on the fly—e.g., with `sorted(d.items(), key=whatever_you_want)`. What are you trying to do that depends on the order of the `g.node.items()`? Whatever it is, there may be a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `g` is a `networks.Graph` or one of the three similar types, `node` is a dictionary of nodes. That's only implied by the documentation, but in [the source](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/classes/graph.py#L210), you can see directly that it's a standard Python `dict`.

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) says, `dict.items()` returns a view on the items "in an arbitrary order which… varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary's history of insertions and deletions."

(If you're using Python 2.x, there's no "view", just a list of pairs, but [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) use the exact same wording for the arbitrary order of those pairs.)

So, this is exactly what you should expect. `items()` gives you the items in an arbitrary order, which changes after an insertion.

If you need to keep track of the order of insertion, you normally use `collections.OrderedDict` for that, or manually keep track of them separately. If you want them in some other order, like sorted, you similarly need to use a different type or do that manually.